# Cannot import RollingOLS: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.regression.rolling'

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am running the following command as described by the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/rolling_ls.html)

```
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
```

But it raises the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.regression.rolling'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a minimal reproducible example, which can be tested by others

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked to is the development version for Statsmodels version 0.11.

As of this post, that has not been released yet. However, there is a release candidate out so it should probably be released in the next few weeks. If you need that feature sooner, you can install the development version from Github.